# Counting Rows that Contain a certain word in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I m kind of new to powerbi and dax and i would like to create a measure that counts the number of rows that contain "CARRYOVER" or "NEW" in description column so if you can help me with an answer it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Mesure = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1,find("CARRYOVER",Table1[description],,-1)+find("NEW",Table1[description],,-1)>0))